# Grouping messages to show latest in overview

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, group-by

I'm trying to show messages in an organized way in my rails 3 app. I'm trying to group the messages by a listing id and showing the latest message in that conversation belonging to the listing.

I'm trying this syntax in my controller:

```
@messages = Message.all(:conditions => { :recipient_id => current_user.id },
                        :group => :listing_id,
                        :order => "created_at DESC")
```

This successfully groups together my messages by listing, however it doesn't show the last message within that group. It shows the oldest one.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? I've tried using the :having clause, but to no avail so far.

Comment: It might help to show the DLL for the SQL table. You have a `created_at` field, which I assume is set when a row is added to the table. Can you define what you mean when you say "last message" and "oldest message" - they seem to be the same thing if you are ordering by the `created_at` field.

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing to get familiar with when using ActiveRecord, is watching your output logs. If you're running your app off localhost, started by `rails server`, then you should be seeing all SQL outputted into your console.

I say 'check your SQL' because your approach doesn't quite make sense. If you want to only select a specific conversation and retrieve its last message, then you should doing something like this:

```
@messages = Message.all(:conditions => 
                      { :recipient_id => current_user.id,
                        :listing_id => params[:listing_id] },
                        :order => "created_at DESC")
```

If you're trying to get the last `Message` for each `Listing`, then you need to work from a different perspective, like so:

```
@listings = Listings.all(:conditions => {:recipient_id => current_user.id},
                         :include => :messages,
                         :order => 'messages.created_at DESC')

last_messages_of_first_listing = @listings.first.messages.first
```